# CodeIgniter URL_TITLE model?

Tags: codeigniter, url-rewriting

Here is example of URl_title CI, i know this code is do this

```
$title = "Whats wrong with CSS";

$url_title = url_title($title, '_', TRUE);

// Produces: whats_wrong_with_css
```

But hot to revers, is there a function in Ci to reverse something like this and return the true value?
like this ?

```
// Produces: Whats wrong with CSS
```

Answer (score 1):

hi you can do it just with simple way

```
$title = ucfirst(str_replace("_",' ',$url_tilte));
echo $title;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would "extend" CI's URL helper by creating a `MY_url_helper.php` file in `application/helpers` and create a function similar to what umefarooq has suggested.

```
/*
 * Un-create URL Title
 * Takes a url "titled" string as de-constructs it to a human readable string.
 */
if (!function_exists('de_url_title')) {

    function de_url_title($string, $separator = '_') {

        $output = ucfirst(str_replace($separator, ' ', $string));

        return trim($output);
    }

}
```

Providing you have loaded the url helper, you will then be able to call this function throughout your application.

```
echo de_url_title('whats_wrong_with_css'); // Produces: Whats wrong with css
```

The second (`$separator`) paramater of the function allows you to convert the string dependent on whether it's been "`url_title`'d" with dashes `-` or underscores `_`